# Coroutines for concurrency within Request-Response

Tags: multithreading, web-services, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say I'm running a simple web server, which allocates 100 threads to handle incoming requests. When a request comes, a thread is assigned and is blocked till a response is available. Once a response is available, the response is sent out and the thread is free again.

To service a request I need to make 2 database calls, and basically sum up the results:

```kotlin
    suspend fun getUserData(username: String): String = {
      val firstName = async { database1.findUser(username) } // a suspended function
      val lastName = async { database2.findUser(username) } // a suspended function
      return firstName.await() + lastName.await();
    }
```

Let's say I had a main method that calls the above method to service a request:

```kotlin
    fun main(username) {
      runBlocking {
        return userData(username)
      }
    }
```

My understanding is that the async code in getUserData will run atop a [Default dispatcher with as many cores as CPUs.](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html)

This suggests the following:

- In addition to the 100 threads I have handling requests, I also have another (smaller) threadpool of ~4-8 threads that are handling the database calls.
- Assuming I have 4 CPUs, and assuming each db call takes ~750ms: If I start receiving 50 requests / second, the 4 threads handling the co-routine are going to be blocked by 4 requests, leaving the other 44 hanging, waiting for a response.

This leads to my questions:

1. Is my understanding correct? Is this actually what happens, or do the 4 threads in the Default-Dispatcher manage an event-loop and so can actually handle a whole lot of IO concurrently, executing all 50 requests at once (assuming db.findUser returns a Future or something).
2. Is there any way (with the fixed 100 threads for request-response, and the blocking nature of those threads), to execute code pseudo-concurrently on the same thread. Since this is IO-bound, I'm looking for something similar to the event-loop model that NodeJS has, except running on the same thread. I just want to execute the database calls concurrently, as opposed to sequentially.

NOTE: I am not looking for a different server / framework. Instead, given what I already have, I'm curious if I can leverage coroutines to increase concurrency. If not, I can just run the queries sequentially.

Comment: You said `db.findUser` is a suspended function, which means it doesn't block the calling thread. `do the 4 threads in the Default-Dispatcher manage an event-loop` -- yes. `executing all 50 requests at once` -- yes. `assuming db.findUser returns a Future or something` -- you said it's a suspendable function so it doesn't return a `Future` but the actual result.

Comment: `My understanding is that the async code in getUserData will run atop a Default dispatcher ` -- you can't just call `async` on its own, you need a `CoroutineScope` to call it on, and it will determine the dispatcher. If you use an empty scope like `GlobalScope`, then the default is the `Default` dispatcher. But you should actually enclose the body of `getUserData` in a `coroutineScope { ... }` block, otherwise the code will leak coroutines in the case of one of the two failing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Isn't that handled by the `runBlocking` that invokes it. If the first `async { ... }` fails, then it'll throw at `firstName.await()`, and the second one basically just keeps going. Won't runBlocking get the error and terminate the second one? It escapes the method, but not the invoking (`runBlocking`) scope.

Comment: Yes, but that means it's not contained within the function, you must use an outside `runBlocking` to fix it. An inner `coroutineScope` is the correct idiom and best practice. The function may or may not be called from `runBlocking`. Also, without `coroutineScope` the code doesn't even compile, there is no `CoroutineScope` for `async` to be called on.